# Lucas n-Step Starting Numbers?

Tags: matrices, number-theory, recurrence-relations, recursion, fibonacci-numbers

I am very interested in n-Step Lucas numbers. Trying to find, the "true starting" values seem to be contentious? I would assume $(1,1), (1,1,1), (1,1,1,1)$; like Fibonacci. However, 2-Step Lucas is $(1,3), (1,3,7), (1,3,7,15)$ one under the powers of 2. [Tony Noe's paper](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/journals/JIS/VOL8/Noe/noe5.pdf).

Or Lucas n-Step are: $(2,1), (2,1,3), (2,1,3,6), (2,1,3,6,12)$ Mr. Piezas mentions $L_k=N_{int}[r\cdot x^k]$ [here](https://www.oocities.org/titus_piezas/Fibonacci.htm).

However, n-Step Fibonacci seems (by some) to be $(1,1), (1,1,2), (1,1,2,4), (1,1,2,4,8)$ [Wikipedia Generalizations of Fibonacci numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalizations_of_Fibonacci_numbers#Fibonacci_numbers_of_higher_order).

I admit, probably my own ignorance. Assuming Fibonaccis of any step started all at (1,1,...,1) forms. So. **There you have it. Which is right for Fibonacci?, and which is right for Lucas (the complement sequence)?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you view Mr. Sloanes OEIS?

1. [2-Step Fib](https://oeis.org/A000045)
2. [3-Step Fib](https://oeis.org/A000073)
3. [4-Step Fib](https://oeis.org/A000078)
4. [5-Step Fib](https://oeis.org/A001591)
5. [6-Step Fib](https://oeis.org/A001592)
6. [2-Step Lucas](https://oeis.org/A000032)
7. [3-Step Lucas](https://oeis.org/A001644) Curious [OEIS Search, here](https://oeis.org/search?q=241%2C443&sort=&language=english&go=Search).
8. [4-Step Lucas](https://oeis.org/A073817)
9. [5-Step Lucas](https://oeis.org/A074048)
10. [6-Step Lucas](https://oeis.org/A074584)

The Fibonacci *inital values are*:

$ \{ 0,1\} $

$ \{ 0,0,1\} $

$ \{ 0,0,0,1\} $

$ \{ 0,0,0,0,1\} $

$ \{ 0,0,0,0,0,1\} $

for the Lucas *initial values* are:

$ \{2,1 \} $

$ \{3,1,3 \} $

$ \{4,1,3,7 \} $

$ \{5,1,3,7,15 \} $

$ \{6,1,3,7,15,31 \} $

*Anyone else want to write MMA code to compute the pattern?* Unfortunately, this shows Mr. Noe's table on page 3 needs updating. Otherwise, it is quite complete.

OEIS has the Lucas 2-S, 3-S, .. pattern as a sequence, too. (
Triangle read by rows, "n" followed by (n-1) terms of (1, 3, 7, 15,...) ) [A143802](https://oeis.org/A143802)

Comment: For more information, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wythoff_array and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas_sequence